# Get value from spinner and change Text View depending on that value

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Ok this should be straight forward but i'm having difficulty with it. So far i've got this code.

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item

        SpinnerFAQ = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + SpinnerFAQ,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faq_answer);
        ExerciseData question = new ExerciseData(this);
        question.open();
        String answer = question.getFaqAnswer();
        question.close();
        tv.setText(answer);

   }
```

SpinnerFAQ is a global variable and it stores the value of the spinner as String.

```
    public String getFaqAnswer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { FAQ_ROWID, FAQ_QUESTION, FAQ_ANSWER};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(FAQ_ROWID);
        int iQuestion = c.getColumnIndex(FAQ_QUESTION);
        int iAnswer = c.getColumnIndex(FAQ_ANSWER);

        //c.getString(iRow) + " " +

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
        {
            if(FAQ.SpinnerFAQ == c.getString(iQuestion))
            {
                result = result + c.getString(iAnswer) + "\n";
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is based on code I've already used, but basically I want to check the Spinner against the Question in my Database and if they match I want to change the Text View to the answer. Right now the FAQ.SpinnerFAQ works fine, but c.getString(iQuestion) always shows up as the last value in the database. This code "result = result + c.getString(iAnswer) + "\n";" works fine without the if statement, so I don't really understand why there is a problem with "c.getString(iQuestion)". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(FAQ.SpinnerFAQ == c.getString(iQuestion))
```

Never compare Strings with `==` in Java, always use `equals()`. Please read: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1267661) and change every String comparison to:

```
if(FAQ.SpinnerFAQ.equals(c.getString(iQuestion)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot :(